# Cast class A to class B without generics

Tags: c#, .net, linq, casting

I have two classes that have no connection to one another :

```
public class A
{
   public String Address {get;set}
}

public class B 
{
   public String Address {get;set}
}

List<A> addressList = DB.Addresses.GetAll();
```

When I do

```
List<B> addressListOther = addressList.Cast<B>().ToList();
```

the output is :

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'A' to type 'B'.

Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: What do you have in mind? Clearly you can't cast one type to another type when they are not related to each other. You can change them to inherit from the same interface (and cast to that interface) or manually copy the properties from one to the other.

Comment: You need to loop the list and assign the one class property to another class property.

Comment: Just because two classes have same properties doesn't mean they are in any way, shape or form related. C# treats such classes as completely different things. If you really want to turn A into B just because they have same properties, you are not looking for casting but for mapping.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Select()` instead of that way:

```
List<B> addressListOther = addressList.Select(a => new B { Address = a.Address}).ToList();
```

Or you can override `explicit operator` in class `B`:

```
public static explicit operator B(A a)  // explicit A to B conversion operator
{
    return new B { Address = a.Address };
}
```

And, then:

```
List<B> addressListOther = aList.Select(a => (B)a).ToList();
```

---

***The reason of this exception:***

`Cast` will throw `InvalidCastException`, because it  tries to convert `A` to `object`, then cast it to `B`:

```
A myA = ...;
object myObject = myA ;
B myB= (B)myObject; // Exception will be thrown here
```

The reason of this exception is, a ***boxed value*** can only be unboxed to a variable of the ***exact same type***.

***Additional Information:***

Here is the implemetation of the [`Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,27bb217a6d5457ec) method, if you interested:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
    IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
    if (typedSource != null) return typedSource;
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return CastIterator<TResult>(source);
}
```

As you see, it returns `CastIterator`:

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
    foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;
}
```

Look at the above code. It will iterate over source with `foreach` loop, and converts all items to `object`, then to `(TResult)`.

Comment: Good explanation :) Got my upvote. Only - the first way you mentioned won't work - see my example

Comment: yeah, you need to correct your first example. `.Select(x => (B)x)` is doing exactly what `.Cast<B>()` does which we know is failing. You can't cast `(B)A`

Comment: @Liam Thanks. Actually, I forgot to explain that he must implement explicitly cast operator.

Comment: @GiladGreen :) If you paid an attention to my comment to my answer 18 minutes ago ... ))

Comment: @GiladGreen Did I manage to explain myself? I wouldn't like to be in a such difficult situation. :( Actualy, I am at the work. I was editing my answer, but then my PM called me. So, I couldn't finish my editing.
Is that OK now?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev - If you say you didn't copy then I believe you :) It was just that the edit was after I posted my edit and it contained the same stuff :) I guess it is just a case of "great minds think alike"

Comment: @GiladGreen :) As I said, you can read my comment and see my edit history, if you want to make it sure. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 4):

They do not inherit from each other so you can't do that. The `Cast<T>` iterates over the collection and tries to cast the items to the specified type.

If you do the following you will fail to0:

```
A a = new A { Address = "a"};
B b = (B)a; // Compile error of: Cannot convert type A to B
```

Instead use `Select` to project new `B` items.

```
List<B> addressListOther = addressList.Select(a => new B { Address = a.Address}).ToList();
```

---

Another way is to override the `implicit operator` in class `A`:

```
public static implicit operator B(A a)
{
    return new B { Address = a.Address };
}
```

And then the followingcode will word:

```
List<A> aList = new List<A> { new A { Address = "a" } };
List<B> bList = aList.Select(a => (B)a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way for me is to introduce a superclass.

```
public class ClassWithAddress
{
    public string Address{get;set;}
}
```

Then you'll derive every class from that class and delete the address property like this:

```
public class A : ClassWithAddress
{
}
public class B : ClassWithAddress
{
}
```

After that you can do your list operations concerning the Address Property with the superclass `ClassWithAddress`.