# How to convert a List to another List with explicit conversion operator without using extension method?

Tags: c#, conversion-operator, explicit-conversion

I added this conversion operator to my class and it works well.
When I pass an object of class `A`, it converts it to an object of class `B`.

```cs
public static explicit operator B(A a)
{
    //Convert A to B
}
```

But when I want to convert a `List<A>` to a `List<B>`, it doesn't work.
I tried the following code, but it doesn't work either.

```cs
public static explicit operator List<B>(List<A> a)
{
    //Convert List<A> to List<B>
}
```

Instead, it throws the following compiler error:

> User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type.

I don't want to use an extension method to cast it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use [Conversion Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/09479473.aspx) for converting list of one type to another.

> C# enables programmers to declare conversions on classes or structs so
>   that classes or structs can be converted to and/or from other classes
>   or structs, or basic types.

As you see, the purpose is to convert one type to another, not the list of that types.

You can use `Select` method instead of that:

```
List<B> listB = listA.Select(a => (B)a).ToList();
```

Comment: We have already defined linq method `Cast` for such conversions: `List<B> listB = listA.Cast<B>().ToList();`

Comment: @YuriyN. `Cast` will throw `InvalidCastException`, because it  tries to convert `A` to `object`, then cast it to `B`. The reason of this exception is, a boxed value can only be unboxed to a variable of the exact same type.

Comment: @YuriyN. Check that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148491/cast-class-a-to-class-b-without-generics/40148572#40148572

Comment: I have class A :B  (A derives from B), no explicit cast operator.
I use IList<A> type and the  IList<A>.Cast<B>().ToList() solution works.

Comment: @Alex75 In case of OP there was no inheritance relationship between classes. But if there is any,  then at first the A's will be converted to object and then to B